# How can I use clearInterval() or some other method to make my fade background script in javascript that uses setInterval() stop?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a nested closure function that is looping and fading my background color based on assignments in the array. On the button with the onclick "stopFadeColors()" method I started, how can I actually stop the script from running by clicking the second button?

```
<style>
.black {
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
    background: #000;
}
.white {
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
    background: #fff;
}
</style>
<script>
//make the element start blinking at a rate of once per second.
function fadeColors(target) {
    var elem = document.body; //assign the object to a shorter named object
    var toggleColor = ["black", "white"]; // setup color list, it can be more than two
    var counter = 0; //outer counter
    var nextColor; //outerClass
    function changeBackgroundColor() {
        console.log(counter); // output count 
        counter = (counter + 1) % toggleColor.length; //modulus of counter divided by counter length
        nextColor = toggleColor[counter]; //update the class 
        elem.className = nextColor; //assign the class
    }
    setInterval(changeBackgroundColor, 1000); //call our function 
}
</script>
<button onclick="fadeColors()">Fade Background</button>
<!-- how can i make this next button call a new or existing method and pause the script with clearInterval() or some other way? --//>
<button onclick="stopFadeColors()">Stop Fade Background</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign your `setInterval()` function to a variable:

```
function fadeColors(target) {
    var elem = document.body; //assign the object to a shorter named object
    var toggleColor = ["black", "white"]; // setup color list, it can be more than two
    var counter = 0; //outer counter
    var nextColor; //outerClass
    function changeBackgroundColor() {
        console.log(counter); // output count 
        counter = (counter + 1) % toggleColor.length; //modulus of counter divided by counter length
        nextColor = toggleColor[counter]; //update the class 
        elem.className = nextColor; //assign the class
    }
    document['intervalTemp'] = setInterval(changeBackgroundColor, 1000); //call our function 
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="fadeColors();">Fade Background</button>
```

Other button onclick to stop:

```
<button onclick="clearInterval(document.intervalTemp);">Stop Fade Background</button>
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was looking for. I had tried using clearInterval() inside my method, but this works great!